# Capitalizing nouns before numbers No

Tags: grammar

When looking at "Inspection Shaft No. 1", I do not know whether I should capitalize all nouns or just the first one in a row.

> - Inspection Shaft No. 1 or
> - Inspection shaft No. 1

Comment: Does it have a label on it? Is is a proper name (a title) or just a common name (a description)?

Comment: No, it is just a part of the sentence. Inspection shaft No.1 is located on ....

Comment: We do capitalize Room No.12, or Test No.2, so this is the case, isn't it?

Comment: If you're using *title case* then words get capitalized. Otherwise, unless they are proper nouns, they do not. If it is not *called* ***Inspection Shaft Number 1***, then you would write ***inspection shaft number 1.***

Answer (score 1):

> Inspection shaft No. 1

is certainly wrong. If this is the name of a place, or is being treated as the name of a place, it is a prope noun and should be in *title case*, as:

> Inspection Shaft No. 1

If it is merely a description, it should be in sentence case, as:

> inspection shaft no. 1

but in no circumstance would the first word be capitalized, and the others not.

By the way it would be better to spell out 'number' rather than use "No." unless the abbreviated form was the standard way in which the place was referred to.